# No aparece console.log en la consola de navegador chrome

Tags: javascript, consola, google-chrome

Buen día tengo un inconveniente al tratar de imprimir en la consola del navegador Chrome un console.log, pues no me aparece nada y empezó a suceder después de haber presionado la primera opción de la lista tal y como se aprecia en la imagen (no se porque lo presioné)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

Comment: ¿nos mostrarías por favor el código que estas tratando de ejecutar?

Comment: Con el código no hay problema amigo porque antes de hacer lo que muestro en la imagen de presionar la primera opción de esa lista si aparecían los console.log

Comment: en default levels el menu mas a la derecha podes reactivar errores warnings y esas cosas. si aún no los ves con f1 podes resetear a default las settings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gracias a todos por responder ya había solucionado el problema y era tal como explica alo Malbarez. En las imagenes se podrá apreciar mejor, lo coloco porque busque en google y no encontré soluciones así que me puse a curiosear en la consola hasta llegar a la solución definitiva. Esto va para alguien que llegue a tener el mismo problema y no sepa como solucionarlo.

[image: Paso 1]

[image: Paso 2]

Y así se podrá apreciar nuevamente los console.log

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada para indicar que el problema ha sido resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

Borra el filtro, el que está en el cuadro de texto al lado del logo con forma de ojo, en tu caso el texto "-url:http://localhost/PROYECTOS/sistventascomp...".

Hice lo propio para quitar el filtro que me impedía ver los mensajes de la url "chrome://newtab/" eliminando lo que resalto a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sí la responde, quizás no la entendieron y por eso la complementé con la captura de pantalla

Comment: la captura ayuda a entender mejor la idea de la respuesta, habrá que ver si resuelve el problema